# Route inbound calls to different SIP Trunks in Asterisk Python

Tags: python-2.7, asterisk, raspberry-pi3, freepbx

I recently started a project to route inbound calls to different softphones.

**What I Did**

I'm using Raspberry Pi to do this. So in raspberry pi I've installed asterisk and python and pyst package to connect asterisk and python. However I want to route incoming call to different softphones in the network based on caller ID. So though to use Zoiper application in several mobiles which have connected to the same Wi-Fi network.

**What I want**

I want to know how can I use python and pyst functions or AGI functions to route incoming call to specific softphone. I know I've to make an asterisk SIP server and add SIP client info to the softphone. But I can't get a proper idea how to do that when it comes to several softphones.

Also I'm running asterisk on freePBX and I'm using Python IDLE IDE. So I wish I could only use codes to accomplish this than setting up by freePBX web GUI. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation availible inside SOURCE of agi.py

```
agi.dial('SIP/trunkname/%s' % newnumber);
```